# Redirect hostname to specific path with Apache

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to get a redirect the requests from an url like myApp.myDomain.com to a specific file on the server like /var/www/html/myApp/index.php.
I need the user to keep seeing the URL he used to get there.

What's the best approach? .htaccess or permanent redirects?

Comment: Please provide a specific example in your question with any code you have.

Comment: What is site root (DocumentRoot) of `myApp.myDomain.com`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use permanent redirects (301) in virtual host file of myApp.myDomain.com. Like,

RewriteEngine   On

RedirectPermanent    /     end_site.com

The 'end_site.com' should be pointed to /var/www/html/myApp/index.php on the corresponding virtual host file.